# ScrollOrientation.Both on Xamarin Forms ScrollView

Tags: xamarin.forms

Does anyone have any suggestions to allow a ScrollView to allow scrolling in any direction.

There seems to be only Horizontal & Vertical ScrollOrientation but no option to do both at the same time.

My end goal is to be able to pinch, zoom & scroll any direction.

Answer (score 4):

Xamarin Forms scrollview's `Orientation` property now accepts `Both` as a value. It scrolls on both direction. I am using Xamarin Forms version 2.3.0.49.

`<ScrollView HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Orientation="Both">`

Comment: This doesn't work for me. It results in a runtime exception. Xamarin Forms version 2.3.3.180.

Answer (score 3):

Here's how you do it.

```
var scroller = new ScrollView { Content = grid, Orientation= ScrollOrientation.Horizontal, VerticalOptions=LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand };
var vScroller = new ScrollView (){Content=scroller};
Content = vScroller;
```

Comment: It does work, but it does not allow for scrolling diagonally.

Answer (score 0):

`ScrollOrientation` is not a `[Flags]` enum and does not contains `Both` value, so this i snot supported at this time. But this could work:

```cs
new ScrollView {
    Orientation = ScrollOrientation.Vertical,
    Content = new ScrollView {
        Orientation = ScrollOrientation.Horizontal,
        Content = your_content_goes_here,
    }
}
```

Comment: It's basically the same code like from user2986451, which does work for me. What is your `Content`? I'm using a `Label` in a `StackLayout` in the inner horizontal scroll view. What doesn't work? Only one scrolling direction?

Comment: the documentation says not to put a scrollview in a scrollview  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/Xamarin.Forms.ScrollView?view=xamarin-forms